# Permission issue running Wpf application in Vista

Tags: wpf, windows-vista

I created a WPF Desktop application and have tried deploying it to vista without success. The application performs a scan and uploads the data to a web service on the internet. It should also log any exceptions using NLog to the hard drive. When I run the application it errors out when trying to send the data to the web service. If I run it as administrator it works fine. I have tried a number of things but nothing seems to work. Nlog doesn't log the exception so it's difficult to tell what is happening. Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I signed my application with strong name. When analzying the evidence information on Vista it shows that the exe is part of the MyComputer zone which has full trust.  Still having issues. Going to attempt to add code to demand WebPermissions.

Comment: Adding a strong name allowed my application to be apart of the MyComputer zone which allow it to contact the web service but it seems access to Itunes Com Api is limited.  Does COM iterop need administrator level rights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a strong name to my application allowed it to be given full trust on the machine. This solved any issues getting to the external web service. Go [here](http://www.csharp411.com/net-assembly-faq-part-3-strong-names-and-signing/) to learn how to sign your application.